# Why does my ReadyNas 4200 have a constant beep post disk failure

Tags: hard-drive, readynas, failed

Went to check on a high pitched constant beep coming from the server room and discovered that all the LED lights on the disks were black except one which had a constant green. Post a Re-boot nothing changed. Console indicated that that particular drive has failed. Pulled the drive out and BAM everything is fine. Except, the high pitched beep remains. Plan is currently to replace the drive with a new same size drive we happen to have purchased for expansion.

My question is, what will this do?

Will the NAS accept the new drive as a replacement for the failed one and decide to shut-up?

The Manual for the device is almost to straight forward and says that I can just swap drives out as I need but I find that difficult to believe:
http://www.readynas.com/download/documentation/HM/RN4200_HW_24May10.pdf

Comment: I'd suggest contacting their support.  Screwing around with a custom raid array based on advice from people on the internet probably isn't going to get your data back.

Answer (score 0):

Had this happen to me tonight for a different situation.  One of the PSU lost power.  I think the gist is, if there is a flashing light in the bottom of the UI, fix that problem.